# How can I use SQL's YEAR(), MONTH() and DAY() in Doctrine2?

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, sql-date-functions

I want to perform a query which would look like this in native SQL:

```
SELECT
    AVG(t.column) AS average_value
FROM
    table t
WHERE
    YEAR(t.timestamp) = 2013 AND
    MONTH(t.timestamp) = 09 AND
    DAY(t.timestamp) = 16 AND
    t.somethingelse LIKE 'somethingelse'
GROUP BY
    t.somethingelse;
```

If I am trying to implement this in Doctrine's query builder like this:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('e.column AS average_value')
   ->from('MyBundle:MyEntity', 'e')
   ->where('YEAR(e.timestamp) = 2013')
   ->andWhere('MONTH(e.timestamp) = 09')
   ->andWhere('DAY(e.timestamp) = 16')
   ->andWhere('u.somethingelse LIKE somethingelse')
   ->groupBy('somethingelse');
```

I get the error exception

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 63: Error: Expected known function, got 'YEAR'

How can I implement my query with Doctrines query builder?

**Notes:**

- I know about [Doctrine's Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html). I've tried this, but it leads to the problem that my productive and my development database tables have different names. I want to work database agnostic, so this is no option.
- Although I want to work db agnostic: FYI, I am using MySQL.
- There is way to extend Doctrine to "learn" the `YEAR()` etc. statements, e.g. as [seen here](http://www.simukti.net/blog/2012/04/05/how-to-select-year-month-day-in-doctrine2/). But I am looking for a way to avoid including third party plugins.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can add [Doctrine extension](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) so you can use the MySql `YEAR` and `MONTH` statement by adding this configuration if you're on Symfony:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

now you can use the MONTH and YEAR statements in your DQL or querybuilder.

Note: The extension supports MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQLite.

Comment: Please notice the third point of my notes list. I know about this extension. But I am asking for a way to avoid this.

Comment: Sorry for that, actually I don't think there is any other way

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Your comment is kind of the answer I was looking for. So I accepted this answer :-)

Comment: What if database is sqlite or pgsql?

Comment: @pikachu0 Editing an answer is more helpful for others than just leaving a comment when correcting an obviously wrong information like here.

Comment: @fishbone by the way, reviewing [your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16597308) I see you missed to see the 2nd line. It is within the parentheses, in _[this][2] if you're using Symfony_

Comment: Why do you think i missed the 2nd line? I removed the Symfony bundle link on purpose, because there is no bundle for the correct extension, however there was a bundle for the wrong extension.

Answer (score 15):

In **Symfony 4** you must install [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions):

```
composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions
```

And then edit the doctrine config file (config/packages/doctrine.yaml) as follow:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

Comment: The question was not about Symfony4

Comment: It helps me a lot searching about DAY(). Even if it is not for Symfony 4, for me helps me for Symfony 4

Comment: @drAlberT Indeed, considering date of the post. But this anszer is kind of an update for people landing here now, so it is appreciable

Answer (score 3):

[orocrm/doctrine-extensions](https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions) seems to be a good project too

It supports both *MySQL* and *PostgreSql* .. the goal is to be **cross DB**

Answer (score 3):

For Symfony 4:

1. **Install:** composer require beberlei/doctrineextensions
2. **Edit:** config\packages\doctrine.yaml

```
    doctrine:
        orm:
            dql:
                datetime_functions:
                    DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
                    MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                    YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

3. **Edit your controller:**

`````
    public function somex()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $emConfig = $em->getConfiguration();
        $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('YEAR', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year');
        $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('MONTH', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month');
        $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('DAY', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day');

        $day = '22';
        $month = '4';

        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u')
            ->from('App\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->where('DAY(u.somedate) = :day')
            ->andwhere('MONTH(u.somedate) = :month')
            ->setParameter('month', $day)
            ->setParameter('day', $month)
        ;
        $trab = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();


        return $this->render('intranet/somex.html.twig', [
            'trab' => $trab
        ]);
    }
    ````
`````

Answer (score 1):

go to [this page](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/config) and choose your database systeme and pick up functions thats you want

...
I too had the same problem as you... then I modified my doctrine.yaml file using exactly the same names as in the github file and it worked.