# Symfony Yearly Sales Report Integration

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine, symfony5

Hello I am trying to make a company sales report generator but I am stuck. I tried to write the code as below but SQL functions are not working:

```
public function getMonthlyReport($company, $year)
    {
    $searchYear = New \DateTimeImmutable("$year-01T-01T00:00:00");
    $searchYearEnd = New \DateTimeImmutable("$year-12-31T23:59:59");


    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('SUM(expenses.price)')
        ->select('SUM(s.price)')
        ->select('MONTHNAME(s.created_at)')
        ->leftJoin('s.Expenses', 'expenses')
        ->andWhere('s.Company = :company')
        ->setParameter('company', $company)
        ->andWhere('s.created_at BETWEEN  :startDate AND :endDate')
        ->setParameter('startDate ', $searchYear)
        ->setParameter('endDate', $searchYearEnd);
    return $query
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

I want a result as below:

```
Month       Sales     Expenses
January     1250      0
February    10000     54879
March       0         4578
April       54000     44567
May         7854      2135
June        6399      8000
July        0         0
August      128000    1200
September   128000    1200
October     128000    1200
November    128000    1200
December    128000    1200
```

Appreciate your helps,
Regards

EDIT 1:
I have written a SQL query  as below but it's only fetching if there is a record on that month(0 if no record presents in that month) and I couldn't execute it in Symfony due to SUM and MONTHNAME functions

```
SELECT SUM(expenses.price), SUM(sales.price), MONTHNAME(sales.created_at) FROM sales left join expenses On expenses.sales_id = sales.sales_id WHERE 1 GROUP BY MONTHNAME(sales.created_at) ORDER BY sales.created_at ASC;
```

Result:

```
Month       Sales     Expenses
November    1650000   5275000
February    2750000   10550000
April       21450000  79125000
March       4950000   15825000
```

Comment: Databases work like that - you can only select what's in the database. When you don't have entries for some month names, then they won't appear in the results. The solution is easy: add the missing months using PHP.

Comment: I have fixed by adding a calender table and a slight tweak in repository, I will post the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what to do and will explain in 3 steps.

First Step:

Create a Symfony 'Calendar' entity with 'month' attribute as datetime.
And Insert 12 months as dd.mm.yy for example; 01.01.2022, 01.02.2022,...

Second Step:

Write a SQL query to fetch Monthnames and left join with your related table(sales and expenses table for this question) as below.

```
SELECT MONTH(c.month) as mOrder,MONTHNAME(c.month) AS mName, (CASE WHEN SUM(e.price) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(e.price) END), (CASE WHEN SUM(s.price) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(s.price) END) FROM calender c LEFT JOIN sales On MONTH(c.month) = MONTH(s.created_at) LEFT JOIN expenses e On e.sale_id=s.id
```

Third Step:

Convert your SQL query to DQL one by one. Install DoctrineExtensions to use functions like MONTH(), YEAR(), DAY(), MONTHNAME() as guided in:

[How can I use SQL's YEAR(), MONTH() and DAY() in Doctrine2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826836/how-can-i-use-sqls-year-month-and-day-in-doctrine2)

And add additional conditions after join statement instead of 'where' clause.
For me the function was like below.

```
public function getMonthlyReportRowsbyCompany($company, $year, $state)
{
    $searchYear = New \DateTimeImmutable("$year-01T-01T00:00:00");
    $fields = array('MONTH(c.month) as mOrder,MONTHNAME(c.month) AS mName', '(CASE WHEN SUM(e.price) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(e.price) END)' ,'(CASE WHEN SUM(s.price) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(s.price) END)');
    if($state == "0")
        $sales_states= ['1', '2', '3'];
    else
        $sales_states[] = $siparis_durumu;
    if($company== "0")
        $company= true;
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->set('lc_time_names', 'tr_TR')
        ->select($fields)
        ->leftJoin('App:Sales', 's', 'WITH', 'MONTH(c.month) = MONTH(s.created_at) AND s.Company= :company AND s.state IN (:state) AND YEAR(s.created_at) = YEAR(:searchYear)')
        ->setParameter('company', $company)
        ->setParameter('state', $sales_states)
        ->setParameter(':searchYear', $searchYear)
        ->leftJoin('App:Expenses', 'e', 'WITH', 'e.sales=s.id')
        ->orderBy('mOrder', 'ASC')
        ->groupBy('c.month');
    
    
    return $query
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Only problem is I couldn't find a way to make 'set('lc_time_names', 'tr_TR')' statement work. Other than that it works perfect.